# Would it be weird if I write "a simple sample something"?

Tags: technical-writing, word-choice

Not getting too technical, I am writing a configuration file for a piece of software I have developed. This software allows others to write "services" and attach them to my software.

I have written a simple service that serves as an example and I have included it in the release bundle. It is the user's choice however, whether to build this service or not.

The part where they select whether to build that service or not, has a help text attached to it. There, I have this sentence:

> This option enables build of a simple sample service ...

Honestly, the "simple sample service" sounds strange to me. Am I being too picky with my words? If not, what alternative do you suggest?

Notes: I certainly want to mention that it is a sample service and it's not meant to be used. I would be happy if I could include "simple" also, to encourage them to take a look at it.

Comment: Proofreading/suggestions for readability are not the best fit here. Maybe writers.SE? Relevant to here, your sentence is perfectly grammatical, but yes, it sounds a little too alliterative for technical prose.

Comment: Actually, I think the alliteration is charming, and I would smile to see it in documentation.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, haha, well I guess it's not _that_ bad!

Comment: Can you provide more of the documentation, to give us context? Also, saying that it sounds strange doesn't give us much to go on. How do you want it to sound? Can you get specific with your concerns?

Comment: @NeilFein, I already got my answer, so no need to worry. I am not a native English speaker and there would have been no way on earth I would known of the word "alliteration". That was what "feels weird" and "kind of strange" were trying to describe. Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: I understand. This is also an odd situation since the question was migrated here, not asked here.

Comment: Unrelated, but you might consider: "This option builds" ... or, "Select this option to build" ...

Comment: @Joe, thanks for the suggestion. The option doesn't "build" the module per se, but your second suggestion fits. Is there anything grammatically/semantically wrong with my sentence, or is yours just a more common phrasing?

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm not technically sure without more context.

Comment: @Shahbaz I'm not technically sure without more context. "Enable build" sounds like two verbs in a row with no object (noun).  While "build" may actually refer to an object in context, it doesn't sound that way.

Comment: @Joe, you are right. I thought I could use `build` as a noun, but the more I think about it, the more I realize I am wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the phrase "simple sample service". However, if you want to avoid alliteration you could use other words that convey the "not for production use" nature of the service:

- test
- prototype
- demo

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You might try substituting the word "*basic*" for "*simple*" - that would eliminate the most awkward part of the alliteration.

Comment: That could also work! I already chose to change `sample` to `demo`, but I'll remember this for another time.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal change needed to avoid disconcerting alliteration is to just call it a *"simple **example** service"*.